# Insert data into blog in WordPress by Json link

Tags: mysql, json, database, wordpress

I want to update my post by JSON link, I have got all post data by this link. 
http://xyz/wp-json/custom/v1/all-posts.
how can I setup cron jobs for auto-update.

Comment: You want to insert post via rest api, isn't it ?

Comment: If it is working fine so i will do this by api

Comment: If you want to migrate the post, you can simply export the all the content and import it in another website.

Comment: No, i want to insert by json code

Comment: Check this out: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/rest-api-create-delete-posts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$slices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://27.109.19.234/decoraidnew/wp-json/custom/v1/all-posts'),true); if ($slices) { foreach ($slices as $slice) {
  $title = $slice[1];
  } } $my_post = array(
 'post_title'    =>  $title,
 'post_content'  => 'This is my content',
 'post_status'   => 'publish',
 'post_author'   => 1,
 'post_category' => array(8,39) ); $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
```